# how to javac some file of spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, javac

A spring boot project when execute `mvn compile` command got below info

```
[INFO] /Users/my/workspace/.../src/main/java/com/.../FooService.java: /Users/my/workspace/.../src/main/java/com/.../FooService.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /Users/my/workspace/.../src/main/java/com/.../FooService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

How to `javac` the FooService.java with `-Xlint:unchecked`? e.g.

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked com/myCom/appName/service/FooService.java
```